# Combining two fast queries results in extremely slow query

Tags: mysql

Query 1:

```
SELECT  a.name,a.id
FROM name_list AS a 
WHERE   a.created_time BETWEEN "2013-03-14 00:00:00" AND "2013-03-14 23:59:59"
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT address_nr
FROM address_list
WHERE user_id="1117770"
LIMIT 1
```

To execute the queries 1 and 2, i just need 0.003 second for both. But when i combine them and make the 2nd query as a subquery, as below:

```
SELECT  a.name,a.id,(SELECT address_nr FROM address_list WHERE user_id=a.id LIMIT 1) as 'address'
    FROM name_list AS a 
    WHERE   a.created_time BETWEEN "2013-03-14 00:00:00" AND "2013-03-14 23:59:59"
```

I need 1 second to execute it. When i am retrieving thousands of data, it needed thousand seconds.

Can someone please guide me in this? Thanks!

Comment: As you've noticed, MySQL queries execute slowly.

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple join?  Looks like you fooled the query engine into executing the inner select once per outer row, which would explain the slowness.  Use the `EXPLAIN` command and add the output to your post.

Comment: Edited title to avoid knee-jerk "close/not constructive" votes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a subquery, try a join. This should be markedly faster:

```
SELECT a.name,a.id,b.address_nr address
    FROM name_list a
    LEFT JOIN address_list b ON a.id=b.user_id
    WHERE a.created_time BETWEEN "2013-03-14 00:00:00" AND "2013-03-14 23:59:59"
```

The reason your subquery is taking so long is because it isn't just running two queries, it's running the one main query and the subquery for every single row in the resultset from the main query. If table a has 1000 rows, you're running 1001 queries.

Comment: Actually i already done like tat before, but it have a same result, which is very slow.

Comment: If the relation between name_list and address_list is ManyToOne, then use an `INNER JOIN`.
Filtering by date is slow think about using [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html).

Comment: `inner join` will actually cut off those records without match, while I need to keep those records.